# contagem de registros por intervalo de tempo

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho 3 tabelas:
aeronave(id_aeronvave, matricula); ocorrencia(id_ocorrencia, data_utc); aeronave_ocorrencia(id_aeronave_ocorrencia, id_aeronave, id_ocorrencia)

Tenho essa listagem de aeronaves por grupos de datas:

```
SELECT
  o.data_utc,
  listagg(a.matricula, ', ') within group (order by a.matricula)
FROM
  aeronave a
  JOIN aeronave_ocorrencia ao ON a.id_aeronave = ao.id_aeronave
  JOIN ocorrencia o ON ao.id_ocorrencia = o.id_ocorrencia
GROUP BY o.data_utc
```

Como descobrir a quantidade de aeronaves de matriculas iguais que estão dentro de um intervalo de 2 meses? Calculando isso pra cada data que possuo na minha base de dados.

Exemplo:

data_utc = 11/08/2020 | matriculas = PPTTN, PATAR | qtd_aeronaves_repetidas = 1 
data_utc = 20/07/2020 | matriculas = PPTTN, PTABC | qtd_aeronaves_repetidas = 1

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente mas não seria a função de agregação COUNT associada à cláusula GROUP BY matricula e o intervalo na cláusula WHERE?

Comment: Você fala contagem da agregação de aeronaves no intervalo ?

Comment: Exatamente. Porém esse calculo tendo como referência os registros de data_utc que possou na minha base.

Comment: Seria uma consulta recorrente ou eventual ? Recorrente eu faria uma tabela agregada carregada via job , eventual um tabela virtual gerada pelo seu select , em ambos os casos um join com ela mesma testando a regra dos meses.

Comment: Consulta eventual mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Tente , talvez fique lento

```
SELECT T1.DATA_UTC , T1.MATS , COUNT(*) QTD
FROM
(SELECT o.data_utc, listagg(a.matricula, ', ') within group (order by a.matricula) mats
 FROM aeronave a 
  JOIN aeronave_ocorrencia ao ON a.id_aeronave = ao.id_aeronave 
  JOIN ocorrencia o ON ao.id_ocorrencia = o.id_ocorrencia GROUP BY o.data_utc) T1,
(SELECT o.data_utc, listagg(a.matricula, ', ') within group (order by a.matricula) mats
 FROM aeronave a 
  JOIN aeronave_ocorrencia ao ON a.id_aeronave = ao.id_aeronave 
  JOIN ocorrencia o ON ao.id_ocorrencia = o.id_ocorrencia GROUP BY o.data_utc) T2
Where t1.mats = t2.mats
and months_between(t1.data_utc,t2.data_utc) between 0 and 2
GROUP BY T1.DATA_UTC , T1.MATS
```

Comment: Mas como eu retorno a qtd de vezes que a matrícula se repete nesse intervalo de 2 meses para cada data_utc?

Comment: o sql é uma base para extrair a junção das datas , editei o mesmo

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Veja se funciona , foi sem teste